# hi, i want display the text in text view sentence by sentence

Tags: android, string, textview

I have a string containing the product details as paragraph, it is from my web service.So I want to display these paragraphs sentence by sentence staring with a bullet.for example

my response is like that

```
{"Product":"Dell XPS 13","Image":"http://dri1.img.digitalrivercontent.net/Storefront/Company/msintl/images/English/en-INTL-Dell-XPS-13-9343-2773SLV-i7-256GB-Silver-Androidized-CWF-01967/en-INTL-L-Dell-XPS-13-9343-2773SLV-i7-256GB-Silver-Androidized-CWF-01967-mnco.jpg","Description":"The XPS 13 isn't just the smallest 33cm (13) laptop on the planet1, it also has a virtually borderless infinity display.,Its Size 32 inch","Price":"68000","Quantity":"6"}
```

From its I take `Description` in to a String and then I want to display it in my Display activity page like below

```
.The XPS 13 isn't just the smallest 33cm (13) laptop on the planet1.

.it also has a virtually borderless infinity display.

.Its Size 32 inch
```

Comment: I am not quite sure about how you would do this using Java, but I would do this in a loop that reads the description one character at a time, with an if statement that inserts a newline if the character is a "." this might not be very efficient though, would be better to save your data in the way that you want to display it.

Comment: use `java.text.BreakIterator`

Comment: Can you please give some example code

Comment: code for BreakIterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as follows:

```
String sentence;
String text = "The XPS 13 isn't just the smallest 33cm (13) laptop on the planet1, it also has a virtually borderless infinity display.";
BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
bi.setText(text);
int index = 0;
while (bi.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
    sentence = text.substring(index, bi.current());
    System.out.println("Your"+"    ." + sentence);
    index = bi.current();
}
```